# How can I plot a 3D (XYZ) graph in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, 3d

I have a table of data, however, it is in 2D (XY):

```
X 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
Y 4 4 4 4 10 15 20 25 25 25 25 25 25 20 15 10 4 4 4 4
```

And the graph obtained will look like this:

[image: 2D Graph obtained based on data above]

So, here is my problem. Actually, I want to plot a 3D graph that will look exactly like the image attached above when we see it in 2D, but to plot the 3D graph, I do not have any ideas about the Z data or Z equation that I need to consider.

Below is the example of 3D graph that I want:
[image]

I am so sorry if my question is confusing. I really hope someone can help me. I need help in identifying the Z equation in order for me to produce the 3D graph.

After the 3D graph is obtained, I need to proceed with calculating its slope. That is why I really need to know how to plot a 3D graph based on the image attached.

Comment: Without any data for Z, a 3D representation would be meaningless.

Comment: could you sketch an idea of what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDywk95VEyo) contains a tutorial for creating 3d graphs in Excel.

Once your X and Y data are properly prepared (in a column and a row respectively), you can enter the Z data in the cells corresponding to each X and Y value. In the video, this is done via a formula.

To create a `Surface` graph like the video demonstrates, click `Insert`, `Other Charts`, then one of the icons under `Surface`.

Other methods of plotting 3d data can be found [here](https://best-excel-tutorial.com/55-advanced/56-charts/207-three-axis-chart) and [here](https://help.xlstat.com/s/article/3d-plot-in-excel-tutorial?language=en_US).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. I have already watched the video, but actually I don't know what equation of Z is suitable to be used in order for me to plot a 3d surface chart that will look like the graph image that I have attached above

Comment: I see you have edited your question. I'm not sure what you mean by "compute its slope." Do you mean the slope of one of the segments like the one from `4, 4` to `8, 25`? If so, there's no reason to create a 3d representation -- doing so adds no new information. If you're talking about the slope of a line on the surface you're describing, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799783/slope-of-a-line-in-3d-coordinate-system) might help you understand the underlying mathematics better.